# Why can't 'a and string unify?

Tags: sml

I'm trying to construct some flexible vector functions, similar to those for non-flexible vectors. I'm getting an error message that I don't understand:

```
> val jimmy = update(john,0,"mccoy");
Error-Type error in function application.
   Function: update : 'a flexVector * int * 'a -> 'a flexVector
   Argument: (john, 0, "mccoy") : string flexVector * int * string
   Reason:
      Can't unify 'a flexVector with string flexVector
      (Different type constructors)
Found near update (john, 0, "mccoy")
Static Errors
```

How is this possible? For what I understand, the 'a datatype is non-specific and could therefore be string...?

Comment: What does your update function look like?

Comment: Does it work for other types, such as `int`?

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't defined `'a flexVector` twice in the same structure (in between the definitions of `john` or whichever function creates `john` and the definition of function `update`)?

Comment: Sorry but I wrote this for about two years ago, I don't even remember sml anymore :P